# How can I display a placeholder for input type=date?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
let dueDate = document.getElementById('dueDate')
dueDate.innerHTML = "date"
```

```html
  <input type="date" id="dueDate" placeholder="Date" class="dueDate"></input>
```

I have this simple input field of date, and instead of the outside looking like "yyyy-mm-dd" I want it to display "date" and when a date is picked it then displays the date,

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder doesn’t work for date type input so you can use onfocus() inside text input field

<input type=“text” placeholder=“date”
onFocus=“this.type=date”>